# How can I force generation of a non-inlined *copy* of an inlined constructor in some unit?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In a DLL (built with MSVC) I have a legacy published class in a C++ header, that declares a non-illine constructor (and non-inline, virtual destructor), defined in a unit. That means that library users expect the constructor implementation in the library.

Due to performance reasons, I would like the constrictor to be inlined for the internal code. However, just defining it inline in the header would mean that users might not find the non-inlined definition in the library. At least that is my understanding - which might be wrong; is it guaranteed by something (in MSVC, or in the standard) that the implementation is emitted for such class?

So the question is: if it's possible to guarantee emitting the implementation of inlined constructor in the DLL in some way, so that inlining would work for the newly compiled code, but existing binaries will still keep finding non-inlined implementation. Since I can't take the address of the constructor, I can't use this trick.

Another way would be to create another constructor, with a dummy argument, to be used in internal code, and leave the old default constructor alone; but if possible, I'd like to avoid increasing the complexity here.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that, for an exported class (say via `__declspec(dllexport)`) all its methods would be exported, including those implemented inline. Just try it - if it doesn't get exported, it would be immediately obvious; your test executable would fail to link.

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik! Indeed, `__declspec(dllexport)` looks very relevant!